# error using mvn spring-boot:build-image - received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Server Error"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I tried using 'mvn spring-boot:build-image' command and get that error..

( I saw that maven have a new way to create an image with spring)

```
 Building image 'docker.io/library/ccc:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
[INFO]
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' 100%
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.998 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-26T15:20:51+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image (default-cli) on project ccc: Execution default-cli of goal org.s
pringframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbu
ilder%3Abase' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Server Error" -> [Help 1]
```

I hope someone can help me fix it or refer me to some sources

This is what I get when using debug mode
I copy the explantion from when the error begin
Hope it will give more information about what happend her

```
[INFO]  > Pulling builder image 'docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base' 100%
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.053 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-26T16:47:33+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image (default-cli) on project ccc: Execution default-cli of goal org.s
pringframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbu
ilder%3Abase' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Server Error" -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image (default-cli) on
project ccc: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/cr
eate?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "received unexpected HTTP status: 500
Server Error"
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.3:build-image faile
d: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" an
d message "received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Server Error"
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.DockerEngineException: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io
%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Server Error"
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute (HttpClientTransport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute (HttpClientTransport.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.post (HttpClientTransport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.DockerApi$ImageApi.pull (DockerApi.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.pullImage (Builder.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.getImage (Builder.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.build (Builder.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.buildImage (BuildImageMojo.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.execute (BuildImageMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

[Relates to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044376/spring-spring-bootbuild-image-gives-http-500-error)

Comment: Try building with debug mode on `mvn spring-boot:build-image -X` perhaps there will be more information in the error logs.

Comment: The failure's come from your local Docker daemon. Its logs may reveal what caused it to return a 500 response.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Docker Desktop worked for me.