# Spring spring-boot:build-image gives HTTP 500 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-engine

I'm trying to containerize a simple spring boot app with a hello world rest service( initialized from spring-inializer site).I have installed in my local environment Docker Desktop for Windows with Kubernetes enabled.
Output from docker version :

```
 Cloud integration: v1.0.23
 Version:           20.10.14
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        a224086
 Built:             Thu Mar 24 01:53:11 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.7.1 (77678)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.14
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       87a90dc
  Built:            Thu Mar 24 01:46:14 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.11
  GitCommit:        3df54a852345ae127d1fa3092b95168e4a88e2f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.3
  GitCommit:        v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Pom.xml content :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-service-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest-service-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I execute the command to build/run image
`./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=springio/rest-complete-service`
I get bellow error :
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.13:build-image (default-cli) on project rest-service-complete: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.13:build-image failed: Docker API call to 'localhost/v1.24/images/create?fromImage=docker.io%2Fpaketobuildpacks%2Fbuilder%3Abase' failed with status code 500 "Internal Server Error" and message "received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Server Error" -> [Help 1]`

Would appreciate any ideas to get past this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387257/error-using-mvn-spring-bootbuild-image-received-unexpected-http-status-500-s) to yours, as they state there, this is actually a docker daemon error, so you would need to check docker [daemon logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#read-the-logs) for any relevant information.